# How to dynamically create controls in .NET MAUI (or Xamarin)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, maui-windows

I need to visualize a database schema of any database. For the sake of simplicity, doing it without links between tables. Now i've fot a column class with name and datatype, a table class with name and list of columns and a DBSchema class with a list of tables. The tables should also be indented in a single row for simplicity. How to visualize the schema if tables quantity and content is unknown?

I've tried using UraniumUI DataGrid to visualize a single table, but couldn't figure out what can I do next as I'm new to MAUI or Xamarin. Here are my classes and method to get the schema:

```
public class Column
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
}
public class DBSchema
{
    public List<Table> Tables { get; set; }
    public void AddTable(Table table)
    {
        Tables.Add(table);
    }
}

public static DBSchema GetDBSchema(string connectionString)
{
    DBSchema schema = new DBSchema();

    var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();

    DataTable tablesScheme = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
    foreach (DataRow table in tablesScheme.Rows)
    {
        string tableName = table["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        DataTable columnsScheme = connection.GetSchema("Columns", new string[] { null, null, tableName });

        List<Column> columns = new List<Column>();

        foreach (DataRow column in columnsScheme.Rows)
        {
            columns.Add(new Column(column["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString(), column["DATA_TYPE"].ToString()));
        }

        schema.AddTable(new Table(tableName, columns));
    }

    connection.Close();
    return schema;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you need here!!

Comment: I recommend writing a "hardcoded" test case, where you create the xaml (or equivalent c#) that creates the view you want, for a specific table, with known columns etc. This of course won't be the "dynamic" solution you want, but if you add that to question, along with a picture (or sql) for the original table, people can help you convert your "hardcoded" version to dynamic code.

Comment: The question too abstract to give a response.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use nested collection view with custom data templates
`<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}" />`

Q is far too abstract for detailed answer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/?view=net-maui-7.0